# Have a dataframe of tweets, wanting to filter out tweets that contain one of a number of keywords in the text with str_detect() in R

Tags: r, twitter, stringr

I have a dataframe of tweets. I want to identify all the tweets that contain at least one reference to a set of countries.

These references can appear in various forms. For instance, a reference to the US might be written as "America", "Washington", "Biden", or a number of other things. I figure the best way to do this is to create a vector for each country containing each value I'm searching for:

`usid <- c("America", "Washington", "Biden")`

`rusid <- c("Russia", "Moscow", "Putin")`

`chnid <- c("China", "Beijing", "Xi jingping")`

`ids <- c(usid, rusid, chnid)`

And so on. Please note that this is just a sample. I have 18 countries that will each have a vector of terms.

I have been using stringr because I thought the str_detect() function would be the best way to do this.

I've tried:

`newdf <- filter(df, str_detect(text, usid))`

This will return ONLY tweets that contain "America" but no other values in the vector and this error message: "Warning message: In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)): longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

When I use:

`newdf <- filter(df, str_detect(text, ids))`

I get seemingly random results and the same error message.

After resolving the above, I'd like to be able to negate certain country vectors within the ids vector. For instance, I'd like to search the dataframe for all country vectors except the US vector:

`newdf <- filter(df, str_detect(text, ids![usid]))`

But I am unsure of the syntax for this.

Comment: You should use "filter" instead of filer

Comment: Haha, good catch. Unfortunately that was just a typo in my post, not in my script. Edited, cheers.

Comment: ok :D So here I have a function that can help solve your Problem. At first let "text" be text <- c("America", "B","C", "Germany"),  then you can check with newdf <- text %in% usid which words match the usid. You can try to combine it with str_detect. Im my case you get the resukt TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE because text[1] matches "America"

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the "text" I refer to in the str_detect function is the name of the column I am filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include 'or'.

Instead of

```
newdf <- filter(df, str_detect(text, usid))
```

You can

```
newdf <- filter(df, str_detect(text, paste0(usid, collapse = "|")))
```

where `usid` becomes `"America|Washington|Biden"`

If you wanted everything except `usid` these two calls do the exact same thing. One uses the argument `negate` in `str_detect`, the other uses the `!` as a negation operator.

```
filter(df, str_detect(text, paste0(usid, collapse = "|"), negate = T))
filter(df, !str_detect(text, paste0(usid, collapse = "|")))
```

If you wanted to use `usid` as a 'not' filter in `ids` you can:

```
notusid <- ids[which(!ids %in% usid)]
# [1] "Russia"      "Moscow"      "Putin"       "China"       "Beijing"    
# [6] "Xi jingping" 
filter(df, str_detect(text, paste0(notusid, collapse = "|")))
```

or (this does the exact same thing)

```
filter(df, str_detect(text, paste0(ids[which(!ids %in% usid)], collapse = "|")))
```

Comment: Thank you, Kat! This worked beautifully. This solution fixed bothe the first and second issue I was having. DO you have any ideas about the third part? How to exclude one vector from the vector of vectors?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've added to my answer to handle that part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for adding this this, but I may have explained myself incorrectly in the question. I believe your solution will return tweets that do not include elements from the usid vector. That is, any word except "America", "Washington", and "Biden". What I'm trying to do is exclude usid from the ids vector. So that instead the filter returns results that include elements from both rusid and chnid but not the usid vector.

Comment: Alright, I've added to the answer again!